# Why is node.js not installing properly on my WSL linux terminal?

Tags: node.js, linux

I tried to install node on my WSL linux terminal, and I get this message when I run node: `/usr/bin/node: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected`

Does anyone know why nodejs isn't being properly installed?

I ran the commands:

```
sudo apt install node
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
sudo atp update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Nodejs with apt is not the goo way to go, instead you could use nvm which is far simple and easy to install on Linux or wsl system.

### Install on wsl using `nvm` (Node Version Manager)

you can find the repo on github at [nvm-sh/nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)

#### Install nvm

```bash
# Install nvm and reload the env variable
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash

# or close the window terminal and reopen it
exec $SHELL -l
```

#### Check if the install was successfull

Type `nvm` on the terminal, if show the help

Otherwise, you can look at the [doc](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-linux) on GitHub

> On Linux, after running the install script, if you get nvm: command
> not found or see no feedback from your terminal after you type command
> -v nvm, simply close your current terminal, open a new terminal, and try verifying again. Alternatively, you can run the following commands
> for the different shells on the command line:
>
> bash: source ~/.bashrc

#### Install nodejs

You can now install the latest LTS version of nodejs with this command, as of now it is `v18.16.0`

```bash
nvm install --lts
```